# RXJS 6 - saving collection after one entity

Tags: angular, rxjs6

This is my `registerOrde`, that saves and Order then a list of OrderedProduct, and then "returns" an Order.

```
private createOrder(order: Order): Observable<Order> {...}
    private createOrderedProduct(orderedProduct: OrderedProduct): Observable<OrderedProduct> {...}
    public registerOrder(order: Order): Observable<Order> {
    return new Observable<Order>(subscriber => {
      this.createOrder(order).subscribe(
        createdOrder => {
          if (order.orderedProducts) {
            let observableBatch = [];
            order.orderedProducts.forEach(orderedProduct => {
              orderedProduct.order = createdOrder;
              observableBatch.push(this.createOrderedProduct(orderedProduct));
            });
            forkJoin(observableBatch).subscribe(
              products => {
                createdOrder.orderedProducts = products;
                subscriber.next(createdOrder);
                subscriber.complete();
              },
              error => {
                subscriber.error(error);
                subscriber.complete();
              }
            );
          } else {
            subscriber.next(createdOrder);
            subscriber.complete();
          }
        },
        error => {
          subscriber.error(error);
          subscriber.complete();
        }
      );
    });
}
```

I would like to have the same behaviour but in a more correct way (i.e. using operators and removing the 'new Observable' instruction). I'm using Angular 6.

What operators should I use? Any advice?